# How do I hide function definition popups for specific Python functions in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For example, I don't want it to show the popup description for `print()` everytime I type it. I do not want to blanket ban all description popups, just want to hide it for specific functions for which I don't need it popping up everytime. Otherwise the description popups for less frequently used definitions are certainly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the function definition popup prompt of the python file in VSCode is provided by the python extension.

VSCode does support some [custom prompt](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) behaviors, but at present, the pop-up prompt for specific python function definition needs to be further improved.

For the `print()` you mentioned, the only changes I can make to its related pop-up prompts are: using `"editor.quickSuggestions": false,` in `settings.json` to turn off the prompt when you enter `print`, but specific information will still pop up when you enter `()`,and then using  `"editor.parameterHints.enabled" : false,` will turn off the `()` prompt.

More reference: [Code analysis settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_code-analysis-settings) and [AutoComplete settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_autocomplete-settings).